# Jackson XML deserialization without a subclass

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have the following XML

```
<foo>
  <bar attr1="value" />
</foo>
```

And a Java class

```
public class Foo {
  private String myAttr;
}
```

The value of attr1 should go to the String myAttr. Can anyone point me in the direction please?
Thank you!

Comment: Why is there this random `<bar>` tag? Pretty sure Jackson wouldn't create it if you serialise this class.

Comment: That could be. But the XML isn't generated with Jackson. It is a given XML that I have to deserialize.